# Is "Are" missed here?

Tags: verbs

Just read this in net:

> If you have wireless/bluetooth speakers, ALWAYS check if they connected before playing ANYTHING...

Is there an "are" missed wrongly before the word "connected in the sentence above?
Or there's a grammatical point about it?

Answer (score 2):

It could be either way, but the word 'are' is not "missing" I think it's more a matter of personal preference then right or wrong, (at least in that example).

It depends on if "connected" is a verb or an adjective in the context. If it is a verb, then it should not have an 'are', if it is an adjective, then it should.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. As it stands, it is grammatically correct.

All of the following are valid and could have differences in meaning in other contexts, but here all mean effectively the same thing:

- ...they connected...
- ...they are connected...
- ...they have connected...

*to connect* is a verb. In this case it is conjugated to fit "they" in the past. In the case of "are connected", "connected" is an adjective. This happens because "connected" can be either part of speech depending on context. To illustrate, here are some examples with words that only fit in one context:

- they exploded ("they are exploded" doesn't really fit)
- they are blue ("they blue" is clearly incorrect)